# Visio API - Error message "OSF is not defined"

Tags: office-js, visio

We've been trying to get the Visio API to work with a Visio Online diagram based on [the example provided in the documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/visio/visio-javascript-reference-overview.md#get-started).

A simple diagram (e.g. two connected shapes) built in Visio Online works and are displayed fine and we can get shape data.

However, a simple diagram created in the Visio 2016 client fails and throws the error `OSF is not defined`.

```js
Error message : "OSF is not defined" 
stack : "ReferenceError: OSF is not defined 
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/embedded/1.0/visio-web-embedded.js:2332:17 
    at new Promise (<anonymous>) 
    at OfficeJsRequestExecutor.executeAsync (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/embedded/1.0/visio-web-embedded.js:2331:20) \
    at RequestContext.ClientRequestContext.syncPrivate (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/embedded/1.0/visio-web-embedded.js:710:36) 
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/embedded/1.0/visio-web-embedded.js:680:54 at <anonymous>"
```

So it seems something is missing in the office.js library.

Are drawings created using the client not supported?

Anyone running embedded Visio (as in not the old webpart) successfully using the new API?

[*GitHub-issue for reference*](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1224)

Comment: Thanks for raising this potential issue. Members of the product team are investigating, and they should respond to this post here on SO (and/or within the corresponding GitHub Issue that you opened) when they have some information for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the response from the product team (also added to the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1224#issuecomment-358897474%5C)):

> The issue has been fixed now. In general, Visio Online APIs support embedding drawings created using Visio Online or Visio 2016. You need to upload the created drawing to SharePoint Online, open it in Visio Online and copy the URL from address bar and use it for initialization through APIs.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.